# How to save do...while status/progress in C?

Tags: c, do-while

I wrote this program, which returns the biggest integer inserted by the user.  Now, I would like the program to return the 2nd biggest integer. I created a new variable (called "status"), which is supposed to increment 1 unit every time the cycle repeats. Then, after the break condition happens, I would step back 1 unit in status variable, in order to retrieve the 2nd biggest number. I would like to follow this line of thought (if it is reliable in C) and I ask you fellows what is wrong with my current implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x, tmp=0, status=0, bigger;
    printf("Insert numbers:\n");

    do{
        status+=1;
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (tmp>=x)
            bigger=tmp; 
        else {
            bigger=x;
            tmp=x;
        }
    }while (x!=0);  

    status-=1;
    printf("The second biggest number is %d.\n", bigger);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you need only two biggest integers?

Comment: I would like the program to return "3" if the user inserts " 2, 5, 1, 3"

Answer (score 1):

If you need only two biggest integers, you can just save them in each iteration, such that you have the `max` and `max2` values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x, max=0, max2=0;
    printf("Insert numbers:\n");

    do {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x > max) {
            max2 = max; // Save the previous max, as the second largest value
            max = x ;   // Save the new max
        }
        else if (x > max2) {
            max2 = x;    // The input is not max, but greater than second max
        }
    }while (x!=0);  

    printf("The second biggest number is %d.\n", max2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The status in your code is just a counter. To solve your problem :

- Use an array to store all the data.
- Make a variable and test it if it is different than the biggest and bigger than all other entries

try this :

```
int main()
{
    int x, status=0, bigger=0, secondbigger=0, Array[50];
    while(true){
        scanf("%d",&x)

        if(x==0)break;

        Array[status]=x;
        status++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<status-1;i++){
        if(Array[i]>bigger) bigger=Array[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<status-1;i++){
        if(Array[i]>secondbigger && Array[i]!=bigger) secondbigger=Array[i];
    }

    printf("The second biggest number is %d.\n", secondbigger);
    return 0;
}
```